# Does test-and-set (tsl) also work on multiprocessor systems?

Tags: lock-free

I learned that test-and-set can work on single processor, but does it also work on multiprocessor systems?

Answer (score 1):

The primary goal of the test-and-set operation is to allow implement spinlocks for mutual exclusion on multiprocessor systems. So it has to work.

Comment: Could you please show me code example? Thanks a lot